# Change the input language shortcut to be like windows

Tags: keyboard, language

I'm mostly using windows or Linux, I'm using mac for my job. I don't want to get use to it because I still use Windows (and probably never try again mac).
I tried to change the input language shortcut to be `alt+shift` but the apple doesn't allow that. There is a way to force the system to change the shortcut?